# Access HTML tags in vaadin label

Tags: label, vaadin

I created a file browser field like below.
Label label= new Label("");

html content added to label tag
input type="file" name="img"

1. How can I get the selected file's name ( if possible with the fake path)
2. Is there an alternative way to approach this ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should not use such hacks to create HTML with labels (use HTML mode only for styling). There are other ways to do it. If u need a file upload, then u should use the VAADIN Upload Component, which is easy to use: https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Upload.html

If u need some other special HTML (other than labels, buttons, etc.) witch special logic, you can create JavaScriptComponents like in this example: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.javascript.html

The example uses a JavaScript component to create a standard input field and a button that sends the value to the server. Just replace the text field with your upload field and its done.

Using VAADIN labels to create HTML can work, but it gets ugly once the application gets bigger. I had huge problems in a project because the previous developer used such workarounds and it took me some time to get used to VAADIN JavaScript components (wtf 4 files for some lines of HTML and sending data from server-client and vice versa) but if u understand how the state and connectors work it is really fun to use :)

Comment: Thanks a lot . I will try your suggestions :)